# Compling makefile of CMU Pocketsphinx with Swing

Tags: makefile, cmusphinx

I am trying to port PocketSphinx to C#. they already have makefile that I need to run. When I run the makefile, I get below error

[Here](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/csharp/Makefile) is the makefile link.

I obtained the following error message.

Error :

```
swig -I.. -I../../../sphinxbase/swig -I../include -I../../sphinxbase/include \
    -csharp \
    -dllimport "libpocketsphinxwrap.so" \
    -namespace "Pocketsphinx" -o sphinxbase.c \
    -outdir gen ../../../sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, swig -I.. -I../../../sphinxbase/swig -I../include -I../../sphinxbase/include -csharp -dllimport libpocketsphinxwrap.so -namespace  Pocketsphinx -o sphinxbase.c -outdir gen ../../../sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [makefile:7: pocketsphinx.c] Error 2
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask]. You might also want to learn about [mcve]

Comment: This error means that the `swig` program (I don't know what that is) couldn't be run because it couldn't be found.  If you know where it is, make sure the directory it lives in is on your `Path`.  If you don't have it installed you'll have to install it before this will work.

Comment: I have added swig.exe to same folder , and still gives error